# Do I need to lock my read-only cache before refreshing it with Ehcache?

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, caching, ehcache

I am making an implementation of Ehcache in a multi-thread environment.
I have 1 thread dedicated for managing and refreshing the cache, and the other threads could invoke it any given time.

The cache is read-only, but refresh every 30 minutes. Does Ehchache automatically manage and lock the read access to the cache while it is updating it? Or do I need to wrap with acquireReadLockOnKey() statements?

```
Ehcache cache = getCache();
cache.acquireReadLockOnKey(element);
try {
    cache.put(element); 
}
finally {
    cache.releaseReadLockOnKey(element);
}
```

UDPATE:
Here are more details on the implementation. The above code is for the "updateCache()" method, but below is how it is initially created.

```
import net.sf.ehcache.Cache;
import net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager;
import net.sf.ehcache.Ehcache;

public class TTLCacheProviderHelper {   
    private CacheManager cacheManager = null;
    Ehcache myTtlCache = null;  
    private static final String CACHE_NAME = "myTTLCache";
    private static int TTL_VALUE = 1800;    
    private static EvictTimeClock evictTimeClock = null;


    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public TTLCacheProviderHelper() {
        cacheManager = CacheManager.create();      
        Cache testCache = new Cache(CACHE_NAME, 100, false, false, 10, 10);
        Ehcache  originalCache = testCache;        
        cacheManager.addCache(originalCache);       
        myTtlCache = cacheManager.getCache(CACHE_NAME); 
        String ttlValue = AppConfigService.getInstance().getTTL();
        if(ttlValue!= null)
            TTL_VALUE = Integer.parseInt(ttlValue);
        evictTimeClock = new EvictTimeClock();
        setEvictTimeClock(TTL_VALUE);
    }

    Ehcache getCache(){
        return myTtlCache;
    }`
```

And its config:
`

```
    <cache name="configCache" maxElementsInMemory="100000" eternal="true" overflowToDisk="false" />

    <cache name="validationTemporaryCache" maxElementsInMemory="10000"
        eternal="false" overflowToDisk="false" timeToIdleSeconds="500"
        timeToLiveSeconds="500" />

</ehcache>`
```

Comment: does it matter if another thread sees an old value while you are refreshing?  if not, then you don't need to lock.

Comment: although, it may depend on whether or not your cache is self-populating.  you should include more details on how your ehcache instance is configured.

Comment: No it doesn not matter if the cache has an old value or not, as long as it doesn't not return an inconsistend object. Do you have references mentioning it is not required having it explictly locked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your scenario is `read -> flush -> recalculate -> put -> read`, then the answer is no, Ehcache does not automagically block all readers until the new value is calculated. What you need to do is to use its [`read-through` mechanism](http://ehcache.org/apidocs/net/sf/ehcache/constructs/blocking/UpdatingSelfPopulatingCache.html) or something similar.

But if your scenario is `read -> recalculate -> replace -> read`, then I don't see a need for any extra locking.

Comment: Well it is multithread, so the thread that controls the cache does this: recalculate -> replace. the other threads just read.

Comment: `Ehcache.put` and `Ehcache.replace` are atomic so as soon as this method finishes, all other `Ehcache.read` methods will get the new value. There's no need for any extra locking here.

Comment: Also, is the default putIfAbsent behavior for multiple threads that only one of them succeeds without any additional write/read locks in EhCache?

Comment: @user469718 you might want to open a separate question for this